# I need to position my navbar within a div

Tags: html, css

I've tried everything from text-align to setting margins. I want the nav bar to be centered horizontally and at the bottom of the div vertically.

html: http://www.joekellywebdesign.com/businesssample/index.html

```
<div id="navbar">
          <ul id="MenuBar1" class="MenuBarHorizontal">
              <li><a class="MenuBarItemSubmenu" href="projects.html">Projects</a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="restaurant.html">Restaurant</a></li>
                  <li><a href="house.html">House</a></li>
                  <li><a href="mall.html">Mall</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
              <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
              <li><a class="MenuBarItemSubmenu" href="services.html">Services</a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a class="MenuBarItemSubmenu" href="residential.html">Residential</a>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="housing.html">Housing</a></li>
                      <li><a href="storage.html">Storage</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                  <li><a href="business.html">Business</a></li>
                  <li><a href="government.html">Government</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>

          </ul>
        </div>
```

css: http://www.joekellywebdesign.com/businesssample/css/styles.css

```
  /* CSS Document */


* {
    margin:0px; 
    padding:0px;
  }

body {
     background-color:#FF0;
     }

#wrapper {
    width:900px; 
    margin:10px auto;
    background-color:#FFF;
  }

#logo {
    float:left; 
    width:200px; 
    background-color:#FFF;
   }

#navbar {
    float:right; 
    text-align:center;  
    width:700px;
    margin: auto; 
    background-color:#FFF;
   }
```

Comment: _"at the bottom of the div"._ Which div?

Comment: You sure you don't mean the #top div?

Comment: nope, I have 2 div's within the top div. I want the navbar to be centered within the navbar div and on the bottom of it.

Comment: You have provided wrong css. You are using SpryMenu and also your `#logo` and `#navbar` are not inside `#top`..

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this,

```
ul.MenuBarHorizontal {
    cursor: default;
    font-size: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 512px;
}
```

Secondly, as per your design, the navbar ends exactly where you ul ends,

so you might try this

```
#navbar {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    float: right;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 49px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 700px;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't make it stick to the bottom of the parent.

Comment: You used an absolute position yet don't set any top, left, bottom, or right parameters. This is not proper code. You don't need an absolute position to use margin-top, and never told him to apply a relative position to the parent container.

Comment: That gets it to the bottom but now it's sitting on top of my logo. I have updated my files on my website so you can see what it's doing now and see the updated code. Thanks for working with me.

Comment: Sorry i wrongly left the `position: absolute;` with my code. Can you try now.

Comment: hmmm, it's still not centered horizontally. text-align:center isn't working.

Comment: I searched google and found a site showing how to center it in design view in dreamweaver. It involved setting a width to the navbar then setting left and right margins to auto. Should I still mark one of these answers as accepted or leave it as unanswered?

Comment: Thats the way my answer is doing. You can notice i have made some fixed width, and made the margin: auto. Which will include your both left & right as auto.

Comment: Secondly if you want the text to be center aligned in the menu bar. You can add `text-align: center` to selector `ul.MenuBarHorizontal a`. Please let me know what your opinion

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    div#container {
        position:relative;
        width: 500px;
        height: 300px;
        border: 1px solid black;    
    }    
    div#menu-container {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }    
    div#menu {
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;    
    }
</style>
<div id="container">
    <div id="menu-container">
        <div id="menu">
            Hello World!   
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Check out [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FTFYk/) for a demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

Using an absolute position would easily get it to the bottom:

1. You'd apply this to the #navbar: `position: absolute; bottom: 0px;`
2. Then you'd apply this to the parent: `position: relative;`

However, now that you've applied an absolute position, you should use a similar technique to center it horizontally. Since your navbar is 700px, we can use some math to center it using the same absolute position.

1. You'd apply this to the #navbar: `left: 50%; margin-left: -350px;`
2. Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ky9av/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
ul.MenuBarHorizontal {
margin-top: 8%;
float: right;
}
```